# what do %(xyz)s representation mean in python

Tags: python

What are these representation in python and how to use. My guess is it is used for data validation but never able to use it.

```
%(name)s
%(levelno)s
%(levelname)s
%(pathname)s
%(process)d 
etc..
```

Comment: In Python 2.6 and later, the `%` operator with a string left hand side is deprecated in favor of the [str.format](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) built-in method.  `"Name: %(name)s\n" % {'name': 'Bob'}` turns into `"Name: {name}\n".format(name='Bob')`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [string formatting using keys](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
>>> d = {"answer": 42}
>>> "the answer is %(answer)d" % d
'the answer is 42'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's formatting a string, by picking values from a dictionary:

```
test = { "foo": 48,  "bar": 4711, "hello": "yes" }
print "%(foo)d %(bar)d and %(hello)s" % test
```

prints:

```
48 4711 and yes
```